# Javascript API Requests

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, vue.js

I have a small issue understanding how to go about this problem in javascript. Below are the question and details. Any help is welcome.

**QUESTION**

Given is a server backend that has two endpoints: /GetLocalPressReleases and /GetGlobalPressReleases. Both endpoints can be accessed using a simple parameterless GET request and will return JSON documents. The format of the JSON document is demonstrated below. Please write JavaScript code that will call both endpoints and create a JavaScript array that contains the information from both sources with an added "source" field that indicates where the information originates from for further processing. The array should be sorted by the timestamp descending. Visualize the output.

**THE CODE**

```
var exampleResultArray = [
{
"timestamp": 150892000,
"headline": "New version of the product announced.",
"link": "http://example.url/new_version",
"authorName": "Paul Abbot",
"authorImageUrl": "http://example.url/authors/abbot.jpg"
},

{
"timestamp": 150892600,
"headline": "Even newer version of the product announced.",
"link": "http://example.url/newer_version",
"authorName": "Lisa Halliday",
"authorImageUrl": "http://example.url/authors/halliday.jpg"
}

];
```

Any help on how to solve this is greatly appreciated. Thanks, guys.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a nested callback, and a global array for storing data from both endpoints.

You can use jQuery.ajax or Axios. If not, use fetch or XMLHttpRequest.

```
var arr = [];
$.ajax('/GetLocalPressReleases',{
    success: (data)=> {
        arr = data.map( x=> x);
        $.ajax('/GetGlobalPressReleases',{
            success : (innerData) => {
               for (const e of innerData){ arr.push(e);  }
               // Do visualizations here
            }
        })
    }
})
```

and of course you'd better catch errors on each level of the nested callback and handle them accordingly. To avoid callback hell, you can use promises ([.done(...).fail(...) in jQuery](http://blog.revathskumar.com/2016/06/why-i-prefer-ajax-promise.html) or .then(...).catch(...) in Axios)

Comment: what exactly does "visualize the output" mean? Does it mean visualize the results in a template HTML? I just need clarification. Thanks.